# Modify Hosts File

Tags: hosts

Has anyone used this method:
http://www.putorius.net/2012/01/block-unwanted-advertisements-on.html

I tried per instructions. Maybe I'm too new to Linux, it's not working for me.

While looking for etc/hosts I came across hosts.allow and hosts.deny. Do I simply add doamains to the hosts.deny list ?

Comment: Which browser are you using? There are much simpler ways to block ads.

Comment: Firefox. Adblock extensions slow the browser down too much, esp with no preloader for linux.

Comment: Noscript is a pretty lightweight way to block ads - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/502201/178596)

Comment: I've used noscript it helped me with a rendering issue I was having in windows that I'm not encountering in linux. It's a bit time consuming I find because of each site needing to be tuned.

Comment: `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` are not `hosts`.

Comment: ok this is a bit confusing. Taken at face value I thought I could block domains by adding them to hosts.deny ?

Comment: `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` is used for granting access to your computer. See `man hosts.deny`.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem there is that it assumes the user is `root`. I modified the script to add in `sudo`, so that any user allowed to use `sudo` can use the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /etc/hosts ~/.etchosts
cd /tmp
wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt
sudo rm /etc/hosts
sudo mv hosts.txt /etc/hosts
cat ~/.etchosts | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

That being said, I recommend you use an extension in whichever browser(s) you use to block ads there instead of messing with `/etc/hosts`. I find the extensions do a better job of blocking ads while allowing content.

Comment: Thank you. I use Firefox and find that adblock extensions slow the browser down too much, esp with no ppreloader for start up. If I run this script is a text editor supposed to open and do I modify anything there, for example like when I modified memory swap settings earlier ? This is all new to me. Thanks

Comment: @user308751: No, nothing is supposed to open. You can either save the script to a file, mark it as executable (`chmod +x fileName`), and then run it (`./fileName`), or just copy the script line by line (starting with the second line).

Comment: ok thank you. Curious, when I try to manually modify any host file then save changes, I get the access denied message. How do I gain access ?

Comment: If you aren't using `sudo`, and you aren't `root`, then you get the access denied message. You can use `sudo vim /etc/hosts` or `sudoedit /etc/hosts` (which uses your default editor) to edit `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: ok got it I was going straight at it, just came over from windows thank you

Comment: thank you for script modification I will try this process when I have time. I still don't understand the "fill the file with the following" part ...... If I'm not in a text editor and not creating or modifying a file then ....... I'm sorry I just don't understand, fresh noob coming over from windows ;-(

Comment: @user308751: Where do you see that? You only have to run the commands above, and the `/etc/hosts` file will contain the list of domains to block.

Comment: So I pasted the script and now the file hosts is deleted and not in the trash either, not good? good? I dunno anymore.

Comment: you must be kidding.... browser extensions are barely blocking any advertisement and/or intermediate tracking sites. For me this is the only and best method I've seen delivering descent results so far. I even run it on all my android devices using DNS66, an application (for obvious reasons) not in the play-store, but works very well using VPN profiles to trash crap traffic to 0.0.0.0.