# Deleted hosts file - how do I move or copy a file to the /etc folder?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I pasted saiarcot895's code from here:
[Modify Hosts File](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502171/modify-hosts-file)

Now my `/etc/hosts` file us gone with nothing in the trash either.

How do I move or copy my custom hosts file from my desktop into the `/etc` folder?

I copy/paste blindly terminal input suggestions as my knowledge level is n00b.

Comment: Do you have a `.etchosts` file in your home directory ? In a terminal do `ls -l .etchosts`

Comment: maybe this can help https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files

Answer (score 1):

The code use copy pasted has made a backup of your original `/etc/hosts` in your home folder by the name of `.etchosts`.
You can remove the file /etc/hosts and then copy the backup in there with the correct name.

```
sudo rm /etc/hosts

sudo cp ~/.etchosts /etc/hosts
```